# Dismiss Custom Dialog when Click on activity

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to make an custom dialog over an activity and able to made dialog successfully.

Now I want to **hide dialog when click on a button of an activity** and not with device back button or on outside click. Problem is - when dialog opens, activity loses focus so it not taking click on the button (what I think)

Here is the constructor of dialog class-

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {

        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cus_dialog);
    }
```

and xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/normal_border"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delete_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/delete_msg"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/work_phone_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/delete_msg"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_yes_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_border"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:textAppearance="@style/labels" />

         <View
            android:id="@+id/gap"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
           />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_no_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_border"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textAppearance="@style/labels" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried -

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

but no effect. I dont know what is happening here.  Please help

**Update** - I tested it on HTC(android 4.0) it is working fine on this device but not working on android 2.3

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform actions on Activity as your Activity will be in **paused** state as soon as your dialog appears on screen. When the dialog appears on screen your method `onPause()` will be called thereby stopping activity from further actions as soon as your dialog dismissed your activity method `onResume()` gets called and allow activity to perform actions.

You can accomplish this by creating your custom dialog in the form of an activity and then in your manifest file set the theme of that activity as dialog.

like this

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Now instead of showing a dialog you need to open this activity by passing an intent and your activity will be displayed in the form of dialog over previous activity.

Now when you run this you will observe when your dialog appears your activity's `onPasue()` Method gets called when the dialog is closed `onResume()` will get called.

Answer (score 1):

Its only one line code try this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout.xml);

    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android 4.0 Dialog gets canceled when touched outside of dialog window
```

try using `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` (boolean cancel) method and pass boolean value to `enable/disable` dialog behavior when touched outside of dialog window.

And for further check [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)